Extension of a function from its domain to the closure of its domian in a general topological space
Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ be a non-empty subset. Suppose $f: A \rightarrow Y$ is a mapping from $A$ to some finite set $Y$. If $x \in \bar{A}$, can we always find a net $\{x_{\alpha}\} \subset A$ such that $f(x_{\alpha})$ for all $\alpha$ is constant?
The motivation of this question is whether we can extend $f$ to $\bar{A}$ is a meaningful way. If $X$ is first-coutable, then we can use sequence convergence to characterize points in $\bar{A}$. For any such sequence, we can always take subsequence so that $f$ is contant along that subsequence. I am wondering if this is still true with net convergence.
Thanks!
